# php created in the root directory

Tags: php, linux

I use account

> dev_hq

I want to create a folder in the root called medias.

I use the command

```
$medias = 'medias';
$path = './root/'.$medias; 
if(!is_dir($path)){mkdir($path, 0777, true); }
```

but the directory is created in

```
/var/www/public/root/medias
```

=> I want to create folders in

```
/home/dev_hq/
```

and link

```
/home/dev_hq/root/medias
```

Comment: You are aware what `./` stands for …?

Answer (score 0):

What are you are doing is absolutely wrong. Please try this code

```
$medias = 'medias';
$path = '../../root/'.$medias; 
if(!is_dir($path)){mkdir($path, 0777, true); }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: from your guidance I have 
/var/root/medias
it false